# what is the file: C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt

Tags: firefox

After I updated to 12.04, a file named `C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt` occurs in my home directory. The content of the file is as the follow:

```
NPP_Initialize : called
NPP_GetValue is called
NPP_SetWindow : called for instance 920c0e28
Window from browser - 77594625
NPP_SetWindow : called for instance 920c0e28
Window from browser - 77594625
NPP_SetWindow : called for instance 920c0e28
Window from browser - 77594625
NPP_NewStream : called for instance 920c0e28, stream 913403b0, URL http://www.xxxxxx.com/attachments/soft/CDGM%20Optical%20Glass%20Catalog.pdf, stream size 36177984, seekable 1
NPP_Write : called for instance 920c0e28, stream 913403b0, offset = 0, length = 16384, streamlength = 36177984
Trying for window attributes
Trying for query tree
NPP_Write : called for instance 920c0e28, stream 913403b0, offset = 16384, length = 16384, streamlength = 36177984
Trying for window attributes
Trying for query tree ......
```

It seems this file is related to Firefox, what's exactly the problem?

Comment: This is a bug as mentioned in [the answer of karolszk](http://askubuntu.com/a/176563/88802): [LP Bug #986841](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/986841). Bugs are offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), so I am voting to close this question. The bug report lists some work arounds you can use in the meantime.

Comment: tempfile=$(mktemp); crontab -l >$tempfile; echo -e "\n# Remove these
annoying files lp#968841" >>$tempfile; echo "0 18 * * * nice -n19
ionice -c3 find ~ -name 'C\:\\nppdf32Log\\debuglog.txt' -exec rm -f
'{}' \;" >>$tempfile; cat $tempfile | crontab -; rm -f $tempfile

Comment: It's a bug and a common question.  I think it should be reopened.

Answer (score 42):

Here's what I found using a helpful link from Tom:

> nppdf32.so is the actual browser plug-in for enabling Adobe Reader
>   PDF-support in Firefox.
>
> There seems to be a bug in the version 9.5.1 of the plugin creating
>   the "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" in the working-directory where
>   Firefox was started. This will normally be the user's home directory
>   if Firefox is started graphically. If you start it from the
>   command-line the "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" file will be created in
>   the directory where you type firefox. There can be multiple such
>   logfiles on your system if the PDF plugin has been started using
>   different working directories.

Comment: If you can live without the plug-in, i.e. read PDFs in full Reader/Evince/whatever instead of browser window, you can safely just delete the file npp /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/nppdf.so

Comment: Note that the path name is just a convention; this is not limited to Firefox or other Mozilla products.  Many other browsers such as Opera look for plug-ins in this directory and vice-versa, packages like Adobe Reader create the directory during installation (even if no Mozilla software was ever installed) and deploy their plug-ins there.

Comment: Note that the file is also created if the plugin has been deactivated in FF.

Comment: On my machine (14.04) the plugin library was called `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper.nppdf.so`.  I installed Adobe Reader a while back before uninstalling it but it left this behind...

Answer (score 23):

If you can't wait for the next update but are willing to hack you can edit nppdf32.so in your plugins directory to replace C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt with ./.nppdf32Log.debuglog.txt  The file will still be created but will be hidden. I used vim with :set bin, searched for debuglog, then used replace mode.

It's a good idea to use a HEX editor as this is a binary file. Take care only to edit the 3 characters `C:\` to `./.`, the second `\` to a `.`, *and nothing else*.